# If one row in two columns contain the same string python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
    id      k1        k2         same
    1    re_setup    oo_setup   true
    2    oo_setup    oo_setup   true
    3    alerting    bounce     false
    4    bounce      re_oversetup   false
    5    re_oversetup    alerting   false
    6    alerting_s  re_setup   false
    7    re_oversetup    oo_setup   true
    8    alerting    bounce     false
```

So, I need to classified rows where string 'setup' is contained or not.

```
And simple output would be:
    id      k1        k2         same
    1    re_setup    oo_setup   true
    2    oo_setup    oo_setup   true
    3    alerting    bounce     false
    4    bounce      re_setup   false
    5    re_setup    alerting   false
    6    alerting_s  re_setup   false
    7    re_setup    oo_setup   true
    8    alerting    bounce     false
```

I've tried something with this, but as I expact, I have error with selecting multiple columns.

```
data['same'] = data[data['k1', 'k2'].str.contains('setup')==True]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), because it working only with `Series` (one column):

```
print (data[['k1', 'k2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('setup')))
      k1     k2
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3  False   True
4   True  False
5  False   True
6   True   True
7  False  False
```

Then add [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all `True`s per row

```
data['same'] = data[['k1', 'k2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('setup')).all(1)
print (data)
   id          k1        k2   same
0   1    re_setup  oo_setup   True
1   2    oo_setup  oo_setup   True
2   3    alerting    bounce  False
3   4      bounce  re_setup  False
4   5    re_setup  alerting  False
5   6  alerting_s  re_setup  False
6   7    re_setup  oo_setup   True
7   8    alerting    bounce  False
```

or [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
data['same'] = data[['k1', 'k2']].applymap(lambda x: 'setup' in x).any(1)
print (data)
   id          k1        k2   same
0   1    re_setup  oo_setup   True
1   2    oo_setup  oo_setup   True
2   3    alerting    bounce  False
3   4      bounce  re_setup   True
4   5    re_setup  alerting   True
5   6  alerting_s  re_setup   True
6   7    re_setup  oo_setup   True
7   8    alerting    bounce  False
```

Another solutions with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elemnt wise check:

```
data['same'] = data[['k1', 'k2']].applymap(lambda x: 'setup' in x).all(1)
print (data)
   id          k1        k2   same
0   1    re_setup  oo_setup   True
1   2    oo_setup  oo_setup   True
2   3    alerting    bounce  False
3   4      bounce  re_setup  False
4   5    re_setup  alerting  False
5   6  alerting_s  re_setup  False
6   7    re_setup  oo_setup   True
7   8    alerting    bounce  False
```

If only 2 columns simple chain conditions with `&` like `all` or `|` like `any`:

```
data['same'] = data['k1'].str.contains('setup') & data['k2'].str.contains('setup')
print (data)
   id          k1        k2   same
0   1    re_setup  oo_setup   True
1   2    oo_setup  oo_setup   True
2   3    alerting    bounce  False
3   4      bounce  re_setup  False
4   5    re_setup  alerting  False
5   6  alerting_s  re_setup  False
6   7    re_setup  oo_setup   True
7   8    alerting    bounce  False
```

Comment: Would this work if I don't have underline ' _ ' before setup, like now in my question, I've edited? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it check string `setup` only

Answer (score 1):

Here's another generic reduce operation without needing `apply`

```
In [114]: np.logical_or.reduce([df[c].str.contains('setup') for c in ['k1', 'k2']])
Out[114]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Detail

```
In [115]: df['same'] = np.logical_or.reduce(
                         [df[c].str.contains('setup') for c in ['k1', 'k2']])

In [116]: df
Out[116]:
   id            k1            k2   same
0   1      re_setup      oo_setup   True
1   2      oo_setup      oo_setup   True
2   3      alerting        bounce  False
3   4        bounce  re_oversetup   True
4   5  re_oversetup      alerting   True
5   6    alerting_s      re_setup   True
6   7  re_oversetup      oo_setup   True
7   8      alerting        bounce  False
```

**Timings**

Small

```
In [111]: df.shape
Out[111]: (8, 4)

In [108]: %timeit np.logical_or.reduce([df[c].str.contains('setup') for c in ['k1', 'k2']])
1000 loops, best of 3: 421 µs per loop

In [109]: %timeit df[['k1', 'k2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('setup')).any(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop
```

Large

```
In [110]: df.shape
Out[110]: (40000, 4)

In [112]: %timeit np.logical_or.reduce([df[c].str.contains('setup') for c in ['k1', 'k2']])
10 loops, best of 3: 59.5 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit df[['k1', 'k2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('setup')).any(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 88.4 ms per loop
```