# If multiple columns contains several characters simultaneously then return True

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the following data `df`:

```
   id               k1            k2
0   1         re_setup      oo_setup
1   2         oo_setup      oo_setup
2   3         alerting        bounce
3   4           bounce  re_oversetup
4   5     re_oversetup      alerting
5   6       alerting_s      re_setup
6   7     re_oversetup      oo_setup
7   8         alerting        bounce
8   9  alerting_bounce        bounce
```

We hope that: if the `K1` and `K2` columns include characters `setup` or `bounce`, return `True`. Otherwise, return `False`. Note that if `K1` contains `setup` and `K2` contains `bounce`, or *vice versa*, this situation returns `False`.

How to achieve it? Thanks.

The expected results are as follows:

```
   id               k1               k2   same
0   1         re_setup         oo_setup   True
1   2         oo_setup         oo_setup   True
2   3         alerting           bounce  False
3   4           bounce     re_oversetup  False
4   5     re_oversetup  alerting_bounce  False
5   6       alerting_s         re_setup  False
6   7     re_oversetup         oo_setup   True
7   8         alerting           bounce  False
8   9  alerting_bounce           bounce   True
```

I try with `df['same1'] = df[['k1', 'k2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('setup|bounce')).all(1)`, it returns the following result:

```
   id               k1               k2   same  same1
0   1         re_setup         oo_setup   True   True
1   2         oo_setup         oo_setup   True   True
2   3         alerting           bounce  False  False
3   4           bounce     re_oversetup  False   True  incorrect result
4   5     re_oversetup  alerting_bounce  False   True  incorrect result
5   6       alerting_s         re_setup  False  False
6   7     re_oversetup         oo_setup   True   True
7   8         alerting           bounce  False  False
8   9  alerting_bounce           bounce   True   True
```

We can see that line 3 and 4 returns the wrong results.

**Reference:**

[If one row in two columns contain the same string python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709488/if-one-row-in-two-columns-contain-the-same-string-python-pandas)

Comment: Can you have both setup AND bounce in the same string? what should happen then?

Comment: Good question, let's say if both two columns contain `setup` and `bounce` simultaneously, return `True`, otherwise return `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and compare the result:

```
s1 = df['k1'].str.extract('(setup|bounce)', expand=False)
s2 = df['k2'].str.extract('(setup|bounce)', expand=False)

df['same'] = s1.eq(s2)
```

Output:

```
   id               k1            k2   same
0   1         re_setup      oo_setup   True
1   2         oo_setup      oo_setup   True
2   3         alerting        bounce  False
3   4           bounce  re_oversetup  False
4   5     re_oversetup      alerting  False
5   6       alerting_s      re_setup  False
6   7     re_oversetup      oo_setup   True
7   8         alerting        bounce  False
8   9  alerting_bounce        bounce   True
```

#### all matches

```
s1 = df['k1'].str.extractall('(setup|bounce)')[0].groupby(level=0).agg(set)
s2 = df['k2'].str.extractall('(setup|bounce)')[0].groupby(level=0).agg(set)
df['same_all'] = s1.eq(s2)
```

Output:

```
   id               k1            k2  same_all
0   1         re_setup      oo_setup      True
1  2a         oo_setup  bounce_setup     False  # only 1 match
2  2b     setup_bounce  bounce_setup      True  # all matches
3   3         alerting        bounce     False
4   4           bounce  re_oversetup     False
5   5     re_oversetup      alerting     False
6   6       alerting_s      re_setup     False
7   7     re_oversetup      oo_setup      True
8   8         alerting        bounce     False
9   9  alerting_bounce        bounce      True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use, change col name and string:

```
def func1(x):
    if 'df' in x['a'] and 'ww' in x['b']:
        return 'True   '
    else:
        return 'False'

df['status'] = df.apply(func1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tested your code, your answer seems to not match the question.